# How to pass multiple values in a for each controller

Tags: jmeter

This is how the test plan looks :

```
Thread group
    Bean shell sampler
    For each Controller
         Graphql request
```

1. In the previous thread I extracted 2 attributes which are id and price. Now this id and price are unique for each case.
2. I extracted these 2 attributes from the json response and stored in a text file separated by colon. Sample below (id : price)

   ```
    123-456-789 : 45.5
    889-332-121 : 60
   ```
3. I need to run the above thread for each such combination i.e. id and price need to be passed at run time to the variable section of graphql request.Using for each controller I am able to pass each of the Ids but how do I pass the corresponding price ?

Comment: Can you give it a try with [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with `:` as the  Delimiter

Answer (score 0):

If you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
id_1=123-456-789
id_2=889-332-121
price_1=45.5
price_2=60
```

The `id` you can get from the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured like:

[image]

And refer it as `${id}` under the ForEach Controller

With regards to the "price" you will need to use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination like:

```
${__V(price_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I did not understand this part :

${__V(price_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}

In  my case this is how id and price are saved :

id_1=63767474775090abc
id_2=63767474776849fre
price_1=64
price_2=34

How do you I pass price to the graphql request